# How to Create Login Screen with an overlay in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have been trying to create an overlay for a login screen in android without any luck.

My scenario is as follows

1. I implemented the login in a class that extends async task.
2. I want to show a transparent full screen overlay with a loading gif image.
3. When the async task completes close overlay and take the user to the main Activity.

I am new to android programming any help will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it works for me:

Create this class:

```
public class LoadingDialog extends Dialog {

    public LoadingDialog(final Context ctx) {

        super(ctx);
        this.setCancelable(false);
        this.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        this.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_loading);
    }
}
```

This is the layout file (dialog_loading.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in your activity:

```
LoadingDialog dialog = new LoadingDialog(yourActivity.this);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: But can i replace the progressbar with an animated gif

Comment: The progressbar is animated, it looks like a simple circle that rotate

Comment: I know but i need my companies logo which is an animated

Comment: You can add what you want in the layout file

Comment: I have tried your code it works just as you said but i want something similar to wit you find on VLC player; when you want to play a video it show a loading screen with a custom image on it before the actual video is played

Comment: I've tried to see what VLC do. I think you could simply set the dialog background as black instead of transparent

Comment: Yes but my gif image is not animating inside android

Comment: After Google searching it seems there is not native support for animated gif. Try to use this library: https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a Fragment logic for the transaction time and change it later to your main activity.

Not sure what do you mean by "transparent overlay".

Comment: I need the new screen to be ontop of the old screen with a transparent effect.

Comment: Thankz for your quick response; Do you have any code you can share

Comment: Hidding the old screen or become transparent and show your image progessively ?

Comment: The old screen will remain visible; hence the transparent overlay